# Question on Joint Probability Distribution Function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

**Question**
The joint Probability Distribution of ($x,y$) is given by-:

$F(x,y) = \begin{cases}
kxye^{-(x+y)} & \text{if} ~~~~ x,y>0\\
0 & \text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$

We have to calculate the $P(A|B)$ where $A$ is ($x<y$)  & $B$ is ($x<2y$)

My attempt..
I have calculated the value of $k$ as $1$.

- Marginal of $F(x)$ is  $xe^{-x}$.
- Marginal of $F(y)$ is $ye^{-y}$.

But how do I calculate the conditional probability...

What I did is the way we use to calculate the value of conditional probability of say $2$ events $A$ and $B$
What I got was $\frac {P(A)}{P(B)}$

What next?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have $$\Pr[A \mid B] = \frac{\Pr[A \cap B]}{\Pr[B]} = \frac{\Pr[A]}{\Pr[B]},$$ since $A \cap B = (X < Y) \cap (X < 2Y) = (X < Y)$.  Next, by symmetry, $$\Pr[A] = \Pr[X < Y] = \Pr[X > Y] = \frac{1}{2}.$$  We cannot do this for $\Pr[B]$, however, so we integrate over a suitable region:  $$\Pr[B] = \int_{y=0}^\infty \int_{x=0}^{2y} xy e^{-(x+y)} \, dx \, dy = \int_{y=0}^\infty ye^{-y} \int_{x=0}^{2y} xe^{-x} \, dx \, dy = \frac{20}{27}.$$

Comment: Sir can you please explain why we can't use the symmetry for calculating P(B)

Comment: @ADITYA Because the region of integration is not symmetric.  The support of the joint distribution can be visualized as the first quadrant of the Cartesian coordinate plane $(X,Y) \in [0, \infty) \times [0,\infty)$.  The joint density is symmetric about the line $x = y$ on this subset, so we can reason that $\Pr[X < Y] = \Pr[X > Y]$, and because $\Pr[X = Y] = 0$ (this event has measure $0$), the result follows.  But we cannot do this for the region defined by $X < 2Y$.  The value we obtained for $\Pr[B]$ shows this event has a nontrivial probability.

Comment: @ heropup thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

$P(X<Y|X<2Y)=\frac{P(X<Y,X<2Y)}{P(X<2Y)}=\frac{P(X<Y)}{P(X<2Y)}=\frac{\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{y}xye^{-x-y}dxdy}{\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{2y}xye^{-x-y}dxdy}.$ Then you can calculate it.